# Calling a method within the same method?

Tags: java, minesweeper

I am trying to make MineSweeper for a project and I am stuck on a certain part. the explode method below works fine but It seems that I cannot call the method within the method. Without posting all the code, I wanted to see if anyone knew if this is a known illegal thing in Java and/or how to bypass it.

```
public void explode(int row, int col) {
    if(board[row][col].mCount==0 && !board[row][col].isMine()) {
        for (int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++) {
            for (int c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++)                        
            if ((r >= 0 && r < user.userRow) && (c >= 0 && c < user.userCol)) {
                board[r][c].setExposed(true);
                if(board[r][c].mCount == 0) {
                    explode(r,c); // <======= PROBLEM LINE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not giving me a compilation error, but it throws an error when I run the game.

Comment: Could you explain what error you're getting? Maybe post a stacktrace?

Comment: `explode2 != explode`. You are not calling the same method. You should post `explode2` method too, as well as the [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace).

Comment: You can have a method call itself, this is called recursion. You should make sure that there is some case where the method will stop calling itself though, or you will get a stack overflow.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to change that to explode(r,c). I am using explode2, which is a different method that does the same thing. This is how get around that error, by using a method with a different name with identical code, which then feeds it into explode3. When I try to use just explode(r,c) withing explode(), I get the following errors:`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at mini.Cell.isMine(Cell.java:26)
 at mini.MineSweeperGame.explode(MineSweeperGame.java:92)
 at mini.MineSweeperGame.explode(MineSweeperGame.java:101)`

Comment: Please post the entire exception as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what's going on. You have your neighbors loops and those I think are correct except you are not excluding the "current" index. That is, in the inner loop, when `r == row` and `c == col` the method calls itself with the same indexes.

Another thing is that subsequent calls will "loop back" and check the previous indexes. For example if you are checking `row == 6, col == 7`, moving on to `row == 6 + 1, col == 7 + 1` will then check `row == 7 - 1, col == 8 - 1`. This might be solved by just checking if the grid position has been already revealed.

```
public void explode(int row, int col) {
    if (board[row][col].mCount==0 && !board[row][col].isMine()) {
        for (int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++) {
            for (int c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++) {

                if (c == col && r == row) { // make sure it's
                    continue;               // not the current index
                }

                if ((r >= 0 && r < user.userRow)
                        && (c >= 0 && c < user.userCol)
                        && (!board[r][c].isExposed())) { // check if
                                                         // already shown
                    board[r][c].setExposed(true);

                    if(board[r][c].mCount == 0) {
                        explode(r,c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could probably do to refactor that so the logic is more clear but anyhow I think that's the cause of the exception.

Also just as a side note, you have this syntax here where the for loop is not a block:

```
for(/* ... ... ... */)
if(/* ... ... ... */) {

}
```

That's probably something you can do without. When you have some code that can potentially crash the program you should keep your syntax as clear and conventional as possible.

Comment: I tried something similar right before I read this post. This is what I did, as well as your suggestion, without any luck :/. 
`public void explode(int row, int col){
  
if(board[row][col].mCount==0 && !board[row][col].isMine())
{
for (int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++)
 for (int c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++){      
if ((r >= 0 && r < user.userRow) && (c >= 0 && c < user.userCol))  
{ 
board[r][c].setExposed(true);
 if(board[r][c].mCount == 0 && (board[r][c] != board[row][col]))
{
 explode(r, c); }
}  
}
} 
}`
But I think you are on the right track, it is going into an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, actually, you're right, it won't be enough. Because when you make a subsequent call to `explode`, it will check the neighbor's neighbors: which include the previous index. For example say you have some indexes `6, 7`, you move on to `6 + 1, 7 + 1` but that call will check `7 - 1, 8 - 1`. You need to work on your logic so it only propagates outwards instead of "looping back".

Comment: It occurred to me you could try just checking if the coordinates are already revealed. I think that should do the trick. That should ensure your recursion always moves outwards.

Comment: Yea you are right, it would just loop forever by going back to the previous coordinates. I added one more condition in the if statement and it took care of it. You da man! I appreciate it.